# Not finding delete option for the repository

Tags: azure-devops

Not finding delete option for the repository . Please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQt37.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a repository, you need to navigate to **`Project Settings`** > **`Repositories`**.

[image]

And you also need to make sure the permission **`Delete repository`** has been set to **`Allow`** for you on the repository.

[image]

Comment: Hi @shyamkumar, Glad that my answer is helpful for you. Maybe, you can mark my answer as the solution of this case. This may be also helpful for other people who are looking an answer for the similar issues. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Bright Ran, I am not seeing option to mark it as answer.